# Best way to add a dynamic popup within options.html in a chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have a Chrome extension that has an options.html file. In options.html, among the different settings, the user can select a sound.

This is what I want:

1. When the user to clicks on a "Select Sound" option in options.html open an in-page popup.
2. In this popup the user can pick a sound category.
3. Display the selected sound category contents in the same popup and allow the user to select one sound from the category.

What is the best way to implement this popup within the options.html page?

It seems that JQuery popup plugins (such as Colorbox) are causing security issues I am not sure how to fix.

Thank you!

Comment: How about jquery-ui? If one popup plugin is sloppy with regards to strict CSP it doesn't mean all are.

Comment: YES! JQuery UI worked. Thank you!